# Python PassportEye not working in Laravel Project

Tags: python, laravel

I am trying to use an external Python script that uses the PassportEye package to read Passport details and I am facing troubles with it
I have made a folder named "scripts" at the very root of my Laravel Project and I am using Symphony Process to run an external script. The code for Laravel is below for reference

```
Route::get('test-process', function() {
  $process = new Process(['python3', base_path('scripts/read-pdf.py')]);
  $process->run();

  if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
  }

  echo $process->getOutput();
});
```

I have used the command `pip3 install PassportEye` to install the Python Package. My python script is below

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import PassportEye
print(PassportEye.__version__)
```

When I run my code, it shows me the error saying

```
3.0.1 Error Output: ================ Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/www/html/PROJECT/scripts/read-pdf.py", line 3, in <module> import passporteye ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'passporteye'
```

I have tried many different solutions from the when but none seems to work. Also, I have confirmed that I have installed Python3 and PassportEye correctly by running the same from the Linux shell by typing

- python3 (This opens the python shell)
- Then typing and running the version command check for PassportEye and it shows the version of the package which is version 2.1.0

Any help of this matter would be highly appreciated